# Deleting and Adding rows to grid

Tags: extjs

I am trying to delete/add rows to a grid.

Let's say for delete, I have created an actioncolumn like this:

```
{
     xtype: 'actioncolumn',
     width: 30,
     sortable: false,
     menuDisabled: true,
     items: [{
          icon: 'images/delete.png',
          scope: this,
          handler: this.onRemoveClick
     }]
}
```

And the handler:

```
onRemoveClick: function(grid, rowIndex){
    this.getStore().removeAt(rowIndex);
}
```

But for some reason, I get the error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getStore'"

I copied the code from [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#cell-editing), but it doesn't seem to work for me.

[image: grid]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope is wrong for you to use `this` at that point.  You can use a variable with the right scope to refer to the grid in your handler, or you can use the `scope` config option of your `actioncolumn`.  See the docs here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Action-cfg-scope

Comment: Yes, you are currect, used Ext.getCmp("routes_grid"); and now itw working ! TY

Comment: do you know how i can add rows? I am having some troubles -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209346/adding-rows-to-grid

Answer (score 2):

that error is saying your this is pointing at your "MyViewport" not your grid or its store