# Adding empty row with combobox and textarea on grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

Is there any possible way to add combobox and textarea first row of grid in extjs 4 like the image showing below. I tried [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220343/adding-an-empty-row-to-a-grid) but it creating a empty row, my requirement is to create a component instead of blank row

[image]

Answer (score 0):

no thats not easy possible but I think you want a grid filter for each column, so look at this: [Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature)

Comment: please correct if i am wrong.Onload it will not populate like this on clicking column header only show this component...